# How to use apply function with list of functions with multiple argument in r?

Tags: r

I repeat more than 10 functions, three or more times for each function in R!! it is very confusing and wasting my time. I understand the idea of apply function but very basic and need a help with this issue.

I have these functions (part of my whole functions):

```
sel_1 <- lower.tri(fam1)  # selector for lower triangular matrix
     if (check.pars & (any(fam1 != 0) | any(!is.na(par11)))) {
          BiCopCheck(fam1[sel_1], par11[sel_1], par21[sel_1], call = match.call())
     }
     sel_2 <- lower.tri(fam2)
     if (check.pars & (any(fam2 != 0) | any(!is.na(par11)))) {
          BiCopCheck(fam2[sel_2], par12[sel_2], par22[sel_2], call = match.call())
     }
     sel_3 <- lower.tri(fam3)
     if (check.pars & (any(fam3 != 0) | any(!is.na(par13)))) {
          BiCopCheck(fam3[sel_3], par13[sel_3], par23[sel_3], call = match.call())
     }


     MixRVM1 <- list(Matrix = Matrix,
          fam1 = fam1,
          par11 = par11,
          par21 = par21,
          names = names,
          MaxMat = MaxMat,
          CondDistr = CondDistr)
     MixRVM12 <- list(Matrix = Matrix,
          fam2 = fam2,
          par12 = par12,
          par22 = par22,
          names = names,
          MaxMat = MaxMat,
          CondDistr = CondDistr)
```

Is there an easy way to repeat these functions?

Comment: you can use the mapply function

Comment: put all ten functions in one function?

Comment: I think you have a typo on line 6, shouldn't it be `is.na(par12)` ? Also it seems you're assigning the same value 3 times to MaxMat1 etc and ConDistr1 etc. You should really work with lists and arrays whenever possible, if your data is not structured you can't use functions that take advantage of object structure.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes, your are correct for MaxMat1 and ConDistr1 that because I work with 3 fam matrix and one Matrix. How I did not see that?? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard without the data, but by following these principles you should be able to improve your code:

if you don't already have your fam and par variables in a neat format (which you should if you have control over it):

```
fam_variables <- grep("fam[0-9]",ls(),value=TRUE)
fam_variables <- sel_variables[order(sapply(fam_variables,function(x){as.numeric(substr(x,4,nchar(x)))}))]
fam <- lapply(fam_variables,get) # assuming there's no missing sel variable from 1 to n!
par_list <- list(list(par11,par12,par13),list(par21,par22,par23))
```

Then you can use apply functions over these lists:

```
sel <- lapply(fam,lower.tri)
sapply(1:3,function(i){BiCopCheck(fam[[i]][sel[[i]]], par_list[[1]][[i]][sel[[i]]], par_list[[2]][[i]][sel[[i]]], call = match.call())})

MixRVM <- list() # we create a list, and we'll keep the same structure for every item (so the name will be the same among elements)
for (i in 1:2){
  MixRVM[[i]] <- list(Matrix = Matrix,
                          fam = fam[[i]],
                          par1i = par_list[[1]][[i]],
                          par2i = par_list[[2]][[i]],
                          names = names,
                          MaxMat = MaxMat,
                          CondDistr = CondDistr)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I still do not have a data. I need to set up these matrices and then simulate a data.  I will try it and see.

Comment: I could not get the idea of `fam_variables`, could you please explan for me.

Comment: You have several variables fam, named fam1, fam2, fam3, and maybe more (I don't know what these variables are). When you have values of the same "kind", it's good practice to organize them in structured data, such as data.frames or lists. my first lines check in the workplace if you have variables named "fam and a number" and put their values in a list. what you should do in your script is define `fam <- list()` and populate it with your value : `fam[[1]] <- some_value` , `fam[[2]] <- some_other_value` etc... try to find some tutorials about lists and arrays in R

Comment: They are matrices.